# AngularJS submit form to db via php

Tags: angularjs

i'm approching angularJS and i'd like to submit a form to db via php.
i tried this but it does not work.
any help?
i get an error when i click the submit button.
thanks.

```
    //index.html
    angular.module("myApp")
    .controller("addUtentiCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.utenteForm = {};
        $scope.submit = function() {
            $http({
                method : 'POST',
                url : 'backInsertUtenti',
                data : param($scope.utenteForm),
                headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
            })
            .success(function() {
                alert("Dati inseriti correttamente!");
            })
            .error(function() {
                alert("Errore inserimento dati!");
            });
        };
    });

    //aggiungiUtente.html
<form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="addUtentiCtrl" novalidate>
        <input type="text" ng-model="utenteForm.nome" name="nome" ng-maxlength="10" ng-required="true">
        <input type="text" ng-model="utenteForm.cognome" name="cognome" ng-maxlength="10" ng-required="true">
        <input type="text" ng-model="utenteForm.citta" name="citta" ng-maxlength="10" ng-required="true">
        <input ng-enable="utenteForm.$valid" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

    //backInsertUtenti.php
<?php
//define of variable for the connection    
$db= new mysqli($host,$username,$password,$db_name);

$sql=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO utenti (id, nome, cognome, citta) VALUES (0, ?, ?, ?)");
$sql->bind_param('sss',$_POST['nome'],$_POST['cognome'],$_POST['citta']);
$sql->execute();
?>
```

Comment: what's the error message ?

Comment: found the error in here "data : param($scope.utenteForm),". where param is a custom function (now i solved it). do you know any smarter way to pass parameter to php so that cam be processed from $_POST variable?